# How do I adjust the opacity of a field when disabled in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, opacity, jtextfield

I have a program that when started disables fields so that the user cant change parameters. However the opacity changes so much that the writing then is not as clear as I would like. I set the font to Bold but this does not help so much and it also looks out of place when not disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really referring to the `JTextComponents`, then I guess what you need is [setDisabledTextColor(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setDisabledTextColor%28java.awt.Color%29), something like this :

```
tarea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
tarea.setText("Hello World!");
tarea.setEnabled(false);
tarea.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```